# Get Restangular object attribute

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, restangular

After receiving`Restangular` object, `myObject`, that looks like:

[image]

To get the `$object: array[2]` field, I do `myObject[0]` and the result is `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
r = Restangular.service("patient_messages")
myObject = r.getList() # This returns the object on picture above
console.log("$object", myObject[0]) # result: $object undefined
```

Can anyone help me get that field?

Comment: Why would you expect `myObject[0]` to have anything when the array is in `myObject.$object`?

Comment: I also tried that. I got an empty array while it should contain 2 objects

Comment: When attaching `myObject.$object` to scope, I can access to the 2 objects inside it from the view. But, I can't `console.log` it from the controller. 
@muistooshort Do you have an idea why `$object` is only readable from the view.

Comment: Is there some AJAX involved? Keep in mind that `console.log` puts a live reference into the console so what appears in `myObject` when you inspect it in the console isn't necessarily what was in it when you called `console.log(myObject)`.

Comment: @muistooshort you're right. That is an angularJs [$q.defer().promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) object waiting for the AJAX response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try this :

```
console.log("myObject", angular.toJson(myObject));
```

You'll get this output :

```
# myObject {"restangularCollection":true,"$object":[]}
```

Which is the real value of `myObject`, an almost *empty* object that will be filled in with data at some moment in the future: when the *call completes* to be precise. That explain the different results.

The **Restangular** instance you created in your **controller** will return a [$q.defer().promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) object which purpose is to allow for interested parties to get access to the result of the *deferred task* when it completes.

So `myObject.$object[0]` doesn't exist yet, your **controller** wont get to it until you invoque the `promise.then()` method which will return a **new derived promise**, that will look like the one you've been watching in your console :

---

replace in your code `console.log("$object", myObject[0])` by this and it will work :

```
myObject.then(function(){
  console.log("$object", myObject.$object[0]);
});
```